# Image warping with shift vectors

Tags: python, image-processing

I need to find a way of warping images with the shift vectors. I found something, let's say, similar, but it cannot be applied to my problem.

Here is a sample image I want to warp:

[image: source image]

Now, I found a way to do it in PIL, here is sample code:

```py
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('Untitled.tif')
grid = [
    [
        # 1
        [0, 0, 300, 300],
        [0, 0, 0, 300, 400, 400, 300, 0]
    ],
    [
        # 2
        [300, 0, 600, 300],
        [300, 0, 400, 400, 500, 400, 600, 0]
    ],
    [
        # 3
        [600, 0, 900, 300],
        [600, 0, 500, 400, 900, 300, 900, 0]
    ],
    [
        # 4
        [0, 300, 300, 600],
        [0, 300, 0, 600, 400, 500, 400, 400]
    ],
    [
        # 5
        [300, 300, 600, 600],
        [400, 400, 400, 500, 500, 500, 500, 400]
    ],
    [
        # 6
        [600, 300, 900, 600],
        [500, 400, 500, 500, 900, 600, 900, 300]
    ],
    [
        # 7
        [0, 600, 300, 900],
        [0, 600, 0, 900, 300, 900, 400, 500]
    ],
    [
        # 8
        [300, 600, 600, 900],
        [400, 500, 300, 900, 600, 900, 500, 500]
    ],
    [
        # 9
        [600, 600, 900, 900],
        [500, 500, 600, 900, 900, 900, 900, 600]
    ]
]
result = image.transform(image.siresultingage.MESH, grid)
```

This is the result image:

[image: result image]

The problem is that in this method I need to specify rectangular areas and another quadrangular area to fit into the first one. My shift vectors are just coordinates (`[x1, y1, x2, y2]`, where `x1` and `y1` are source coordinates, and `x2` and `y2` are the target coordinates) so what I need is a method to do such warping with different grid, eg:

```py
grid = [
#    x1   y1   x2   y2
    [300, 300, 200, 200],
    [600, 300, 700, 200],
    [300, 600, 200, 700],
    [600, 600, 700, 700]
]
```

The result (If I did not make a mistake) would be exactly the same, but the input data is similar to what I have. The important thing is I need to use TPS as the interpolation method. I tried to find solution in opencv, PIL, scikit image and GDAL, but no success so far. Does anyone know such methods?

I might have not described the problem completely, so please ask if there is something unclear.

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Comment: The expected result is a warped image with given points moved to different positions. The rest of the image should adjust automatically (using TPS interpolation). Basically, it's just like in the second image I posted, but the warping method should be different.

Comment: No, I'd like to see a resulting image. The second image does not reduce to shifts at all.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. It should return the same image as the input, but the given points should be moved and the rest of the image should adjust to the shifted vectors. It's like when you would drag some points to different positions - the points near to the dragged ones would also move. I don't know how to explain it better.